# table name is not appearing right after Create Query in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

i am creating new table using sql server query but when it created, it does not show the right name.below is picture.

[image]

i am trying to create table name as activity_file but it shows leadattendant.activity_table but should be like dbo.activity_file.

kindly help me out?

Comment: Have you refreshed the `Tables`? By right-clicking `Tables` and clicking refresh, or by clicking F5 while having `Tables` highlighted?

Comment: Maybe you have now two tables with similar name in the schemas dbo and leadattendant. So, refresh your object explorer.

Comment: Why do you think that it should be `dbo.activity_file`? The first part is scheme which depends on your login and user mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the table in the Object Explorer, you have to right click on *Tables* and click *Refresh*. The new table does not automatically show up.

If you want your table in the *dbo* schema, change your statement to:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.activity_file
```

When you have multiple schemata, you should explicitly state what schema you want the table created in.